# I can't POST to same page the form is on in Joomla 2.5 in a secure page

Tags: post, joomla, joomla2.5

I have a set of users.

I have a form that they have to log in to get to.

Each user has their data that they put in the same form.

The problem is that when I have the form METHOD set to POST, I get this error :

```
You don't have permission to access /index.php/[path to page here]
```

I am using Joomla 2.5 and a plugin that lets me write php to the article page. Any ideas on what Im doing wrong?

edit : I should add that the ACTION has the URL of the same page the form is on. I have also tried the SEF URL and using JRoute with the same results.

edit 2 : and I AM logged in.

Comment: Holy crap I figured it out. [damn enter button here makes you post]. OK, you know how joomla likes to replace email addresses with javascript? One of the text boxes was holding an email address, which when rendered was script, which joomla barfed on. Removing that textbox the error goes away. Well played, joomla... well played. //squint evilly in joomlas direction

Comment: Do you use multilingual?